# C# Is it possible to set a memory limit size for a DataTable object?

Tags: c#, .net

I know DataTable has a [Minimum Capacity Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.minimumcapacity(v=vs.110).aspx) but is there a Maximum Capacity Attribute? Where if a maximum size is reached while filling the object with data an exception is generated?

e.g:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
{
  SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
  da.Fill(table); //generate exception if DataTable is filled with too much data (e.g. over 100mb in size)
}
```

Comment: You could derive your own custom `DataTable` type that implements such a setting. (Or you could stop using `DataTable`, as it's an awful memory hog compared to the alternative of typed collections.)

Comment: Why don't you limit it in your query...most dbms have some way to do that easily...eg. row_number in oracle

Comment: @Ctznkane525 I can't because some columns have NVARCHAR(MAX) property

Comment: do you want to limit the number of rows...or the length of data in the cells for each row...there's a big difference there

Comment: @Ctznkane525 just limit the result set in mb. 1 row could hold theoretically  several gigabytes

Comment: Theoretically or actually? It's fairly simple to write a `DataTable` that counts row sizes and stops accepting new rows if it hits a limit, but that's useless if one row is already a few gigabytes, because it will already have been allocated and processed by the time the table would get round to checking. In fact, the only way to take that into account is by dropping down to `SqlDataReader`. Alternatively, use `SqlConnection.StatisticsEnabled` and then monitor the result of `SqlConnection.RetrieveStatistics()["BytesReceived"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Two part answer:

1. The Minimum Capacity attribute is *number of initially allocated data rows*, and not
   related to bytes / MB used. One row could be 10 bytes or multiple MB, depending on what you are trying to load.
2. .NET will allocate what it needs until it can't anymore (see [System.OutOfMemoryException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.outofmemoryexception)), which I believe to be true for most if not all allocations. You can't limit this, unless you take control of *all code and especially all allocations* and start counting bytes, which I wouldn't recommend. I can't  think of any classes in the Framework with support for this.